# Is a QR code with a secret URL that changes every 5th minute secure?

Tags: passwords, url, obscurity, qr-code

I need to verify that survey respondents are in the same physical room or video chat (to prevent industry espionage). The respondents can join by scanning a QR-code that opens a URL which embeds a code with 61 bits of entropy. The code and QR changes every 5 minutes.

**However, as URLs tend to be considered security by obscurity, I'm a bit uncertain about allowing QR code sign in. Is this secure, or should respondents enter the code by hand instead?**

Also, is 61 bits of entropy adequate?

And if this is insecure, would changing the QR code more rapidly provide greater security? I could make the code expire in 20 seconds and swap it after 5 seconds and achieve adequate usability.

Comment: I don't think it's really obscurity since it's still a secret, the same as a short-lived password in a POST request.

Answer (score 1):

Those kinds of controls usually fail fast. It takes one person to do a video chat to another outside, and the QR can be sent in real time elsewhere.

61 bits of entropy is more than adequate for a code that expires in 5 minutes. And I don't see any problems by using an URL with quick expiration to login. It's the same mechanism that a lot of services uses for quick login. It's the *magic link* that, for example, Slack sends you to login.

The main issue is not the URL, is that making sure people are in the same room is not easily solvable.

Comment: I think expecting a qr code to work over a streamed video is generous when half the time I seem to have trouble grabbing it IRL.